# Can you teleport twice with two move actions and still hide?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, movement, stealth, meldshaping

The Totemist soulmeld blink shirt bound to his totem chakra allows you to teleport as a move action. Can you teleport twice, and still use hide/hide in plain sight?

Answer (score 3):

#### A creature that uses the *blink shirt*'s teleport effect can't take any actions until the creature's next turn

The soulmeld *blink shirt* (*Magic of Incarnum* 60-1) has its most serious limitation stated in its initial description: "After using this ability, you can’t take any other actions until your next turn" (*MoI* 61).

This limitation remains when the *blink shirt*'s bound to the totem chakra, the description of which, in its entirety, says, "You can use the *dimension door* ability of this soulmeld as a move action" (*ibid.*).

That is, binding the *blink shirt* to the totem chakra changes the time to activate the *dimension door*-like effect from a standard action to a move action but changes nothing else.

Comment: Will update question, A blinkshirt bound to totem chakra has the additional text "You can use the dimension door ability of this soulmeld as a move action and act afterwards" so it would work with dimension door.

Comment: @Simon Please tell me there's double-secret errata for *Magic of Incarnum* that, until now, I've been unaware of! Or is that, sadly,--because my *MoI* doesn't say that--a house rule?